Plot changes when using position_nudge to move bar position in ggplot2 stacked bar chart
I am trying to move the horizontal position of the bars in my ggplot2 stacked bar chart so that the x-axis tick marks are aligned with the left-hand edges of the bars rather than being centered
Example:
data1
        Status Age  Percent
1          low 8.0 19.04762
2          low 8.5 30.23256
3          low 9.0 38.16794
4 intermediate 8.0 45.23810
5 intermediate 8.5 39.53488
6 intermediate 9.0 25.95420
7         high 8.0 35.71429
8         high 8.5 30.23256
9         high 9.0 35.87786

Figure 1 aligns the bars correctly but changes the bar length (should sum to 100%) and y axis length (maximum should be 100%)
Figure1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = Percent, x = Age, fill = Status),
    data = data1, stat = "identity", width = 0.3,
    position = position_nudge(x = 0.25)
  ) +
  xlim(7.5, 9.5)

Figure 2 plots the data correctly but bars are centred on y axis tick marks
Figure2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = Percent, x = Age, fill = Status),
    data = data1, stat = "identity", width = 0.3
  ) +
  xlim(7.5, 9.5)

I want a plot in which the data are portrayed correctly and the left-hand edges of the bars are aligned with the y-axis tick marks

Thanks - similar question although  geom_bar(just = 0, stat = 'identity') suggestion in answer below worked perfectly

Setting just = 0 (default is 0.5) will align the x-axis tick marks with the left edges of the columns.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data1, aes(Age, Percent, fill = Status)) +
  geom_bar(just = 0, stat = 'identity')


